# How can I get a waitbar to work in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to have a waitbar for an operation that takes quite a while. Here is my code:

```
h = waitbar(0,'Please wait...');

for i=1:counterend
    waitbar(i/waitbarcounter)
    Atemp    = At+i*step;
    handle   = @(M) 1/M^2*((2/(gamma+1))*(1+(gamma-1)*M^2/2))^((gamma+1)/(gamma-1))-(Atemp/At)^2;
    Mach     = fzero(handle, 5);
    Aplot(i) =  Atemp/At;
    Tplot(i) = Tc / (1+(gamma-1)*Mach^2/2);
    Mplot(i) = Mach;
    plot(Aplot, Tplot)
end

close(h)
```

The error Matlab gives is:

> ??? Error using ==> waitbar at 249
>   Improper arguments for waitbar

After investigation, I am sure that this error must occur because of the sorrounding code in the loop.

*Note: The loop works fine without the waitbar.*

Comment: Your example runs perfectly fine on R2010a on OSX. Did you check that your example works? Also, are you sure that `counterend` is a scalar double?

Comment: Please not that I substantially changed my question. This possibly makes some of the answers below useles. I am deeply sorry if I should have wasted anyone's time, being quite new to Stackoverflow. If anyone thinks deletion makes sense, I will follow with voting for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running

```
counterend = 10000;
>> h = waitbar(0,'Please wait...');

for i=1:counterend
    waitbar(i/counterend)
end

close(h);
```

Works as expected on 2007a / Windows XP.

On a side note, it would help knowing what countered is defined as.  Something quick to check would be to ensure that you are not passing it a CELL.

Running

```
counterend = {10000};
h = waitbar(0,'Please wait...');

for i=1:counterend
    waitbar(i/counterend)
end

close(h);
```

Yields a different error (see below) in 2007a, but this error message may have changed in 2008.

> ??? Undefined function or method
>   '_colonobj' for input arguments of
>   type 'cell'.

My last bit of advice would be caution you on the use of waitbar for large arrays/data sets.  While I think it is important to inform the user of the progress, to me there is also a concern for how much time is added to the loop.  Working with arrays that have 100k+ entries, I became a religious user of the Profiler to see where the time was really being spent.  I can tell you the time is not in the calculation of the i/X, it was all in updating the waitbar's display.  To soften the blow of the update/drawnow, I only updated the waitbar every 100 to 1000 entry which helped tremendously.

EDIT:  Updated response to match latest code

I first started to attack this problem at the anonymous function, having problems with them in the past it's a personal vendetta of mine.  When looking into the function I found that you are using gamma,  do you have this defined as a constant (constant to the loop / function)?  The reason I ask is that 'gamma' is a Matlab function and was giving me errors when trying to run your function by itself.  Below I have modified you code slightly and this does run fine here.  If any of the assumptions I have made are wrong please let me know.
In addition, if you did intend to use the gamma function, your function is missing any arguments to it.  Hope this helps!

```
clc
h = waitbar(0,'Please wait...');
counterend = 1000;
waitbarcounter = counterend;
g_amma = 7;
At = 34;
step = 2;
Tc = 42;

for i=1:counterend
    waitbar(i/waitbarcounter)
    Atemp    = At+i*step;
    handle   = @(M) 1/M^2*((2/(g_amma+1))*(1+(g_amma-1)*M^2/2))^((g_amma+1)/(g_amma-1))-(Atemp/At)^2;
    Mach     = fzero(handle, 5);
    Aplot(i) =  Atemp/At;
    Tplot(i) = Tc / (1+(g_amma-1)*Mach^2/2);
    Mplot(i) = Mach;
    plot(Aplot, Tplot)
end

close(h)
```

Regards,

Adam

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experiences. I have made some tests and I can confirm your point that the time is spent mostly in updating the waitbar when running a short loop.

In my case, however, I want the user to be able to cancel an operation and see its progress, as he himself can set the length of the loop indirectly. That is why I apply the waitbar.

Your test loop runs fine, but I am still experiencing problems with my case.

Comment: Is this the complete code? If its possible can you add what 'counterend' is set to?  Also I do not see where 'waitbarcounter' is defined.  I would assume that they are equal, can you confirm that?

Answer (score 3):

I have checked `waitbar` on R2008b. So far, the only ways I was able to reproduce your error was by having `i/counterend` evaluate to an array with multiple rows (a 1x2 vector gives interesting results), and by closing the waitbar before calling `waitbar(i/counterend)`.

I do not get any error running the following:

```
h = waitbar(0,'Please wait...');
counterend = 1000;
for i=1:counterend
    waitbar(i/counterend)
end
close(h)
```

Could you make sure that the small example above runs without error? If yes, please check that the waitbar is not closed during the execution of the loop, and that `counterend` is a scalar (use `dbstop if error` to stop execution of your code at the time of the error).

If the above example does not work without error, you should use `which waitbar` to check that you are using Matlab's waitbar, and not any of the many updated version from the Matlab File Exchange.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I definitely use Matlab's waitbar.
Running the example works fine. Following your hints I checked "counterend"s filetype and it turned out it was of the type double. Casting it to "waitbarcounter = uint8(counterend)" does not help as well, though.

On a side note: After restarting Matlab this morning it suddenly stopped giving me an overview of the variables. See [here](http://gerth-ac.de/matlab_screen.png). Any help on that?

Answer (score 1):

Running

```
counterned=1000;
h = waitbar(0,'Please wait...');

for i=1:counterend
    waitbar(i/counterend)
end

close(h)
```

works perfectly as expected on MATLAB R2009a on Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

The above runs fine on R2008a on XP also.

However, you get the error you describe if you kill the waitbar window before the next `waitbar` command comes around. If you want to be nice about it you should check if the handle `h` is still valid before issuing `waitbar`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this is apparently not where the error lies though.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use [progressbar](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6922) written by Steve Hoelzer on the MATLAB FEX. I haven't had any problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your suppose to use the handle that you created with your first line of code when you want to update the waiter,
Waiter(it/itmax,h,'progress')

Comment: add more details to your answer